# Sort Thousands of Chuck E. Cheese Tickets

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, multidimensional-array

I need to sort an n-thousand size array of random unique positive integers into groups of consecutive integers, each of group size k or larger, and then further grouped into dividends of some arbitrary positive integer j.

In other words, let's say I work at Chuck E. Cheese and we sometimes give away free tickets. I have a couple hundred thousand tickets on the floor and want to find out what employee handed out what but only for ticket groupings of consecutive integers that are larger than 500. Each employee has a random number from 0 to 100 assigned to them. That number corresponds to what "batch" of tickets where handed out, i.e. tickets from #000000 to #001499 where handed out by employee 1, tickets from #001500 to #002999 were handed out by employee 2, and so on. A large number of tickets are lost or are missing. I only care about groups of consecutive ticket numbers larger than 500.

What is the fastest way for me to sort through this pile?

**Edit:**
As requested by @trincot, here is a worked out example:

I have 150,000 unique tickets on the floor ranging from ticket #000000 to #200000 (i.e. missing 50,001 random tickets from the pile)

Step 1: sort each ticket from smallest to largest using an [introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) algorithm.

Step 2: go through the list of tickets one by one and gather only tickets with "consecutiveness" greater than 500. i.e. I keep a tally of how many consecutive values I have found and only keep those with tallys 500 or higher. If I have tickets #409 thru #909 but not #408 or #1000 then I would keep that group but if that group had missed a ticket anywhere from #409 to #909, I would have thrown out the group and moved on.

Step 3: combine all my newly sorted groups together, each of which are size 500 or larger.

Step 4: figure out what tickets belong to who by going through the final numbers one by one again, dividing each by 1500, rounding down to nearest whole number, and putting them in their respective pile where each pile represents an employee.

The end result is a set of piles telling me which employees gave out more than 500 tickets at a time, how many times they did so, and what tickets they did so with.

Sample with numbers:
where k == 3 and j = 1500; k is minimum consecutive integer grouping size, j is final ticket interval grouping size i.e. 5,6, and 7 fall into the 0th group of intervals of size 1500 and 5996, 5997, 5998, 5999 fall into the third group of intervals of size 1500.

Input: [5 , 5996 , 8111 , 1000 , 1001, 5999 , 8110 , 7 , 5998 , 2500 , 1250 , 6 , 8109 , 5997]

Output:[ 0:[5, 6, 7] , 3:[5996, 5997, 5998, 5999] , 5:[8109, 8110, 8111] ]

Comment: Are the group's ranges known beforehand? If in your example you would get an input of 1499 and then 1500: then you would say they are adjacent and belonging to the same group...but you have made a division line at 1500. What  are the dividends? Can you give a more elaborate example, using *k*?

Comment: @trincot yes, the ranges are known beforehand. Dividend is not the exact right term but I used it because at the end I am narrowing down what tickets belongs to who by dividing the ticket # by 1500 and rounding down to the nearest whole number. I updated the question to include employee number zero.

Comment: I don't really understand what the output is that you expect. Could you provide a fully worked out example, including input and expected output for it?

Comment: @trincot sure, I will update it now

Comment: @trincot I added a numerical example with sample input and output. Do you have a suggested solution?

Comment: How would your output look if you also had 10,11,12 in the input? And what is the "dividend" in this example?

Comment: @trincot the new output would be [ 0:[5, 6, 7,10,11,12] , 3:[5996, 5997, 5998, 5999] , 5:[8109, 8110, 8111] ]

Comment: 10,11, and 12 are all consecutive and conform to a group size of 3 or larger. To find what "dividend" each of those n-integers belong to, I apply this formula: (round down ( n / j ) ) * j

Comment: Oh, I get it. I think we call that "partition".

Comment: YES! partition is a much better word, thank you @trincot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it in Python:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def partition(data, k, j):
    data = sorted(data)
    start = data[0]  # assuming data is not an empty list
    count = 0
    output = defaultdict(list)  # to automatically create a partition when referenced 
    for value in data:
        bucket = value // j  # integer division
        if value % j == start % j + count:  # in same partition & consecutive?
            count += 1
            if count == k:
                # Add the k entries that we skipped so far:
                output[bucket].extend(list(range(start, start+count)))
            elif count > k: 
                output[bucket].append(value)
        else:
            start = value
            count = 1
    return dict(output)

# The example given in the question:
data = [5, 5996, 8111, 1000, 1001, 5999, 8110, 7, 5998, 2500, 1250, 6, 8109, 5997]

print(partition(data, k=3, j=1500))
# outputs {0: [5, 6, 7], 3: [5996, 5997, 5998, 5999], 5: [8109, 8110, 8111]}
```

Comment: How intuitive was this solution for you? and do you have any tips or resources to help me improve the way I create algorithms? Your solution elegantly answered this through a single `for` loop whereas mine at a minimum needed three. Thank you.

Comment: Intuition comes by doing. So for that I would personally suggest taking on code challenges, and really many of them, especially those where *after* you have submitted a solution, you can check what others have submitted, and their comments. There are many such sites, and they all have their pros and cons. I myself was active on codewars, leetcode, and projecteuler.

Answer (score 1):

Here is untested Python for the fastest approach that I can think of.  It will return just pairs of first/last ticket for each range of interest found.

```
def grouped_tickets (tickets, min_group_size, partition_size):
    tickets = sorted(tickets)
    answer = {}
    min_ticket = -1
    max_ticket = -1
    next_partition = 0
    for ticket in tickets:
        if next_partition <= ticket or max_ticket + 1 < ticket:
            if min_group_size <= max_ticket - min_ticket + 1:
                partition = min_ticket // partition_size
                if partition in answer:
                    answer[partition].append((min_ticket, max_ticket))
                else:
                    answer[partition] = [(min_ticket, max_ticket)]
            # Find where the next partition is.
            next_partition = (ticket // partition_size) * partition_size + partition_size
            min_ticket = ticket
            max_ticket = ticket
        else:
            max_ticket = ticket

    # And don't lose the last group!
    if min_group_size <= max_ticket - min_ticket + 1:
        partition = min_ticket // partition_size
        if partition in answer:
            answer[partition].append((min_ticket, max_ticket))
        else:
            answer[partition] = [(min_ticket, max_ticket)]

    return answer
```

Comment: I will verify/test this approach shortly, thank you for the help.

Comment: not quite., it needs to account for consecutiveness. The grouping size should account for the total amount of consecutive tickets not just the distance between tickets i.e. there could be missing ticket numbers in the pile between the max and min. I added a numerical test example to my question

Comment: @newswiftcoder Not sure what you mean.  My code only includes tickets in a group when they are consecutive, and therefore can use distance to count them.  `print(grouped_tickets([5 , 5996 , 8111 , 1000 , 1001, 5999 , 8110 , 7 , 5998 , 2500 , 1250 , 6 , 8109 , 5997], 3, 1500))` prints `[(5, 7), (5996, 5999), (8109, 8111)]` which is (after format differences - I print the ends of the range while you print everything between) the output you said that you wanted for your test case.

Comment: @newswiftcoder Can you produce an example where my code does NOT produce the result that you asked for?

Comment: this input: `print(grouped_tickets([5 , 5996 , 8111 , 1000 , 1001, 5999 , 8110 , 7 , 5998 , 2500 , 1250 , 6 , 8109 , 5997,9,10,11], 3, 1500))` prints `[(5, 7),(9,11),(5996, 5999), (8109, 8111)]` when it should instead print `[(0,((5, 7),(9,11)), (3,(5996, 5999)), (5,(8109, 8111))]`. The output needs to include partition counts. Your solution is fast though

Comment: @newswiftcoder I updated the code to get the partition as well.